# Undefined index image in PHP, I know this is duplication but I have tried many solution but none worked

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make an application in android where user uploads photo and that uploads will be inserted in my MySQL database using PHP

but my PHP script generates an error that

```
Undefined index image in PHP
```

following is my PHP files-

"Constants.php"

```
<?php
$db_name="mydb";
$local_username="root";
$local_password="";
$server_name="localhost";
$conn= 
mysqli_connect($server_name,$local_username,$local_password,$db_name);
if($conn)
{
echo "Connection successful";
}
else  
{
echo "Connectionj failed";
}

?>
```

"imageUploadScript.php"

```
<?php
require "Constants.php"; 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
 {
  $DefaultId = 0;
  $image = $_POST['image'];
 $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
// if(isset($_POST['image']))
//{ 
 $ImagePath = "imageUploads/$mobile.jpg";
 $ServerURL = "yourPath/$ImagePath";
 $InsertSQL = "INSERT INTO info (img) values('$ServerURL') where 
mobile=$mobile";
 if(mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSQL)){
 file_put_contents($ImagePath,base64_decode($ImageData));
 echo "Your Image Has Been Uploaded.";
mysqli_close($conn);
 }
 else{
 echo "Please Try Again";
 }
//}
}
?>
```

any help from your side will be appreciated

Comment: If you are uploading image you need to use `$_FILES['image']` instead of `$_POST['image']`.

Comment: image uploads deals with `$_FILES` global variable not `$_POST`. so change that and check

Comment: use `file_put_contents($ImagePath,base64_decode($Image))` instead of `file_put_contents($ImagePath,base64_decode($ImageData))`

Comment: thanks @M A  and @ Alive to Die now the error gone but ,controls went to else part and out generated is" Connection successfulPlease try again"

Comment: thanks @Bunny but still the control is in else part

Comment: Then go check for SQL errors. The INSERT WHERE query looks odd.

Comment: then check your insert query and you also have to change the variable: `$imagedata` to `$image`

Comment: VTC as too broad. That's way too many bugs for one question. Find a better tutorial, invest more time on proper indentation and formatting, use those mixed case variable and path names less excessively, read up on PDO and parameter binding, and use an IDE with debugger to analyze such issues.

Comment: thanks @mario i have now corrected the code and it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For uploading an image, you need to use

```
$_FILES['image']
```

instead of

```
$_POST['image']
```